# Can I clean up orphaned inodes before they cause my file system to be unbootable?

Tags: filesystems

Running an HTPC on Linux Mint 20. Every 3 months or so the htpc will become unresponsive and when I reboot it it turns out there are some orphaned inodes. I run `fsck` and the process cleans them up.

Is there some way to clean them up ahead of time without involving being dumped to initramfs?

Answer (score 3):

Orphaned inodes do not collect on a running system.  They are a result of processes having files open when the system is shut down uncleanly.

If you run fsck and there are a lot of orphaned inodes, a program probably has a file descriptor leak (it is opening files and never closing them).  But if there are only a few, it's probably just from shutting it down uncleanly.

If it is becoming unresponsive, then either a program has a bug (like a memory leak or a file descriptor leak) and running the system out of resources until it gets wedged.  Possibly updating software might fix bugs like this, but without debugging code on the system there is no guarantee an update would fix it.

Probably the best solution is to reboot the system more often in a controlled way rather than waiting for it to crash.

Comment: Maybe a cron job to reboot once a week?

Comment: That's one option.

Comment: is there a better option?